# group rows by first character in foreach

Tags: php, smarty

I have foreach loop

```
{foreach from=$rootCategories item=category}
    <li id="parentCategory" data-category="{$category.id_category}">
        <span>
            <img alt="{$category.name}" src="{$base_dir}img/c/{$category.id_category}.jpg" width='46' height='26'>
            <h1>{$category.name}</h1>
        </span>
    </li>                               
    {/foreach}
```

Current output is:

```
Ajp Alter beta black cpanle cupa
```

I want it to be

```
A Ajp Alter
B beta black
C cpanle cupa
```

I have used that code in foreach

```
$lastFoundLetter = ''; 
$firstLetter = {$category.name|substr:0:1} 
{if {$firstLetter} != {$lastFoundLetter}} //you've started a new letter category
 {if {$lastFoundLetter} != ''} //if there's a real value in $lastFoundLetter, we need to close the previous div </div>
 {/if } 
<div id="{$firstLetter}"> {$firstLetter} "<br/>"
{ $lastFoundLetter} = {$firstLetter}; </div> 
{/if}
```

but its not working i think i have used wrong code.Guys plz help me

Comment: You seem to be using smarty - I've added that tag

Comment: I want to see some efforts.

Comment: @u_mulder am try this but not working   $lastFoundLetter = ''; 
 $firstLetter = {$category.name|substr:0:1} 
{if {$firstLetter} != {$lastFoundLetter}} 
        //you've started a new letter category
        {if {$lastFoundLetter} != ''} 
            //if there's a real value in $lastFoundLetter, we need to close the previous div 
            hhh
       {/if }
        <div id="{$firstLetter}">
        {$firstLetter}  "<br/>";
       { $lastFoundLetter} = {$firstLetter};
    </div>
  {/if}

Comment: @user3450650 Please click "edit" under the question and add that code; it will be a lot easier to read than in a comment.

Comment: @IMSoP I have edit it in question.Please help me to solve it

Comment: You shouldn't really change your question in that way. My answer was correct and now you change what it want to be so I need to add another answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code for changed question :

```
{assign  var = 'lastFoundLetter' value= ''}
{foreach from=$rootCategories item=category}
{assign  var = 'curFirstLetter' value= {$category.name|substr:0:1|upper}}

{if $curFirstLetter neq $lastFoundLetter} 
    {if $lastFoundLetter neq ''}<br />{/if}
    {$curFirstLetter}
    {assign  var = 'lastFoundLetter' value=$curFirstLetter} 
{/if}
{$category.name}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

That code will do what you want:

```
{assign  var = 'lastFoundLetter' value= ''}
{foreach from=$rootCategories item=category}
{assign  var = 'curFirstLetter' value= {$category.name|substr:0:1|upper}}

{if $curFirstLetter neq $lastFoundLetter} 
    {$curFirstLetter}
    {assign  var = 'lastFoundLetter' value=$curFirstLetter} 
    {$category.name}
{else}
     &nbsp; &nbsp;{$category.name}
{/if}

<br />
{/foreach}
```

It was tested in newest Smarty 3.1.18

Result for this code is:

```
A Ajp
  Alter
B beta
  black
C cpanle
  cupa
```

so the same you expected

Comment: Thanks working plz tell me I need o/p like A Ajp Alter
B beta black
C cpanle cupa  i mean it will be new row for next alphabet character